# DB search between two dates skipping first result

Tags: java, date

This is my code:

```
String sql = "select bId, bQuantity, bTotal from billsMaster where bDate BETWEEN ? AND ? ";
//and bDate between ? and ?
try {
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    //pst.setString(1, tf_itemSearch.getText());

    pst.setString(1, tf_startDate.getText());
    pst.setString(2, tf_endDate.getText());
    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    if (rs.next())
         tbl_billSearch.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)); 
} catch (SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

The first occurrence of `resultset` didn't insert it to `tableModel`. So, the results from the sql query are : `5`, `3`, `1`, `6`, etc. `5` not inserted to table model, though. Why not?

Comment: What are the types of `tf_startDate` and `tf_endDate` and why you are transforming them to Strings?

Comment: Don't pass dates as strings. Pass a proper `java.util.Timestamp`

Comment: you should use a `do{ //setModel} while(rs.next());` instead of the `if`

Comment: guys .. the problem is in the way that used in resultset .. rs.next() remove first element when populate tableModel ...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
if (rs.next())
```

[`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) increments the result set cursor, therefore the instruction after it will exclude the first result. What you probably want is [`isBeforeFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isBeforeFirst()), which returns `false` if the cursor is not at the beginning of the result set OR if the result set is empty.

Comment: i used this code 
    if (rs.next()){
             rs2=pst.executeQuery();
             tbl_billSearch.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs2));
             }
it works .. OK 
 but is it legal?? .. or make mistakes in hard use?!!

Comment: What is `rs2`?? What do you mean by 'legal'? (Does the compiler let you do it? Then it is...'legal'.) You need to be more clear when asking follow ups.

Comment: it is work perfectly .. I mean ... this new code I execute the query itself second time .. is this way right because I worried about future bugs come out and fall in complex problem

Comment: Great Nathaniel Ford ... when I used isBeforeFirst(), it is run perfectly ... it is working now ... thank you too much